# Pergola Material for Desert Climate

Tags: wood, outdoor, carpentry, backyard, pergola

I'm building a roughly 12'x12' pergola on a concrete slab in my backyard in Las Vegas.  Planning on attaching to house via ledger board.  6x6 posts will be set on metal post bases attached to concrete with retrofit anchor bolts epoxied in the concrete.  All this to say, none of the lumber will be in contact with the ground and there is very little threat from moisture.  What wood should I use?  Does it need to be treated?  I'm okay with a bit of maintenance like staining every couple years, but don't want something that will twist itself into oblivion.  Will most finish the pergola with opaque white stain.

Comment: What wood would you like to use?  Cedar is popular for this, and other woods might not be available in the sizes you want.